# Ruby on Rails - serving assets ourselves vs S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

We are trying to improve our site performance. As part of that, we are planning to do 2 things:

1. all static images are served via S3. This way, the images are served cookie-less.
2. we have a bunch of other static content - javascript, CSS, images such as our logo, etc. We are wondering what the best way is to serve these.

Currently, they are simply stored in the assets folder. This is nice & easy, and since Rails attaches a fingerprint to cache bust, all our current needs are met. However, going forward, we realize that this is not the right way to serve up these images (our logo, etc).

So what's the best way to serve this sort of content?

Thanks!
Ringo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using S3, then I would put all of these files on S3 too.  Then use AWS CloudFront (Content Delivery Network) so that they get served up fast.  The cost of CloudFront is really negligible.

You can use a gem like https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync to make it easier to manage.